# Can one form a view into diagonal of ndarray in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Simple slices form views into the parent array. The strides of the view is generically the multiple of the strides of the parent array.

Given 2d parent array with strides `(s0, s1)`, the 1D array with strides `(s0+s1)` gives the view in the diagonal of the parent array.

Is there a way to create such a view in top-level Python/numpy? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `as_strided` I can do what you want:

```
In [298]: X=np.eye(5)
In [299]: X.strides
Out[299]: (40, 8)
In [300]: np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(X,shape=(5,),strides=(48,))
Out[300]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

though some would argue the `as_strided` is a step closer to the 'guts' than most of `numpy` Python code.

I can do the same striding by indexing on the flattened array:

```
In [311]: X.ravel()[::6]
Out[311]: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
```

(here the `X` values were changed by a `view` test).

Comment: This is useful information, but `.as_strided` does not return a view, but rather a copy. Let `Y = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(X,shape=(5,),strides=(48,))`, then   `Y.base is X` gives `False`.

Comment: The `__array_interface__['data']` value is the same.  I don't know why the `.data` attribute gives a different `hex` location.  Also changing values in this diagonal changes values in the original.

Comment: Interestingly, your answer reveals that strides need not divide each other, as they do when slices are formed. In particular, the following is a valid ndarray: `Z = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(X,shape=(5,5),strides=(7,5))`.

Comment: Be careful though with `as_strided`; it allows you to index memory outside of the data buffer.  So it can be dangerous if used carelessly.

Comment: `X.ravel()[::6]` does the same thing - viewing the array as 1d and then stepping every 6.

Comment: Be careful: there are cases where `ravel()` makes a copy.  For example, `a = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4); b = a.T; br = b.ravel()`.  `br` has a *copy* of the data in `b`.  The strides of `b` do not allow a 1-d view of its data in the standard order.

Comment: Make that `ravel(order='K')` to accommodate order changes by `.T`.

Comment: That might help in some cases, but it is doesn't guarantee that a copy is not made.  For example, try `a = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5); b = a[::2, ::2].T; br = b.ravel(order='K')`.  You'll see that `br` has a copy of the data in `b`, not a view.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using numpy 1.9 or later, and a read-only view is sufficient, you can use [`numpy.diagonal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html).  The docstring says that in some future version of numpy, `numpy.diagonal` will return a read/write view, but that doesn't help you now.  If you need a read/write view, @hpaulj's suggestion to use `as_strided` will work.  I suggest something like

```
diag = as_strided(a, shape=(min(a.shape),), strides=(sum(a.strides),))
```

Be sure to read the "Notes" section of the `as_strided` docstring.

Answer (score 0):

For a version that works on more than 2 dimensions:

```py
import numpy as np


def diagonal_view(array, axis1=0, axis2=1):
    """Return a view of the array diagonal."""
    assert array.ndim >= 2
    axis1, axis2 = min([axis1, axis2]), max([axis1, axis2])
    shape = list(array.shape)
    new = min([shape[axis1], shape[axis2]])
    shape.pop(axis1)
    shape.pop(axis2 - 1)
    shape.append(new)
    strides = list(array.strides)
    new = strides[axis1] + strides[axis2]
    strides.pop(axis1)
    strides.pop(axis2 - 1)
    strides.append(new)
    diag = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(array, shape=shape, strides=strides)
    return diag


def test_diagonal_view():
    # test correspondence with np.diagonal
    for array in [
            np.random.randn(10, 4),
            np.random.randn(10, 4).T,
            np.random.randn(10, 4, 8),
            np.random.randn(10, 4, 8).T,
            np.random.randn(10, 4, 8).swapaxes(0, 1),
            np.random.randn(3, 4, 8, 5),
            np.random.randn(3, 4, 8, 5).swapaxes(0, 2),
    ]:
        for axis1 in range(array.ndim):
            for axis2 in range(array.ndim):
                if axis1 != axis2:
                    result = diagonal_view(array, axis1=axis1, axis2=axis2)
                    # compare with np.diagonal
                    reference = np.diagonal(array, axis1=axis1, axis2=axis2)
                    np.testing.assert_array_equal(result, reference)
                    # test that this is a modifiable view
                    result += 1
                    reference = np.diagonal(array, axis1=axis1, axis2=axis2)
                    np.testing.assert_array_equal(result, reference)


test_diagonal_view()
```